# Better parallel processing python lib without using Hadoop in python

Tags: python, dictionary, parallel-processing, reduce

I don't want to setup a hadoop cluster but still would like to use parallel processing and map reduce in python. Are there any existing libraries in python that does this job ?.

Comment: I'm not sure what setting up a hadoop cluster has to do with this but here is a good blog post on parallel MR in python: https://mikecvet.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/parallel-mapreduce-in-python/ and this was number one on a google search for python parallel map reduce!

Comment: PySpark is another one

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do parallel computing and even MapReduce without using Hadoop or any other heavy frameworks. You can use a package pp for processing in network or multiprocessing for parallel processing across multiple cores. A simple map function can be written as below:

```
import pp

def map(func,args,nodes=None):
    if nodes is not None:
        job_server=pp.Server(ncpus=num_local_procs,ppservers=nodes)
    else:
        job_server=pp.Server(ncpus=num_local_procs)
    jobs=[job_server.submit(func,input) for input in args]
    return [job() for job in jobs]
```

You can also look at sample codes here:
https://github.com/gopiks/mappy

Answer (score 0):

`Pool()` from `multiprocessing` may be what you are looking for. Bellow is an example from somethng I have worked on today. There are other ways to this. Youtube has some good stuff. Check outh videos on [this series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lu5LrKh1Zno).

```
from multiprocessing import Pool  

def process(c_id):
    try:
        # A single process that you want to do
        # Ex. do things and save it in file
    except:
        # something else

def main():
    pool = Pool()
    while True:
        ids = get_new_set_of_ids()  # has to be an itterator having the same size as your number of cores
        pool.map(process, ids)      # map() function maps the processes with the number of cores
```